# Use jQuery add() to add element in a loop

Tags: jquery

How do I use jQuery's `add()` to add an element in a loop?

http://jsfiddle.net/smqtxtnt/2/

```
var allFields1 = $([]).add($('<input/>')).add($('<input/>').add($('<input/>')));
console.log(allFields1);

var allFields2 = $([]);

$([1,2,3]).each(function (index) {
    var input=$('<input/>').val(index);
    allFields2.add(input);
})

console.log(allFields2);
```

I see why my above code doesn't work as described by https://api.jquery.com/add/:

> The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv unchanged:
>
> ```
> var pdiv = $( "p" );
> pdiv.add( "div" ); // WRONG, pdiv will not change
> ```

...but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the result:

```
allFields2 = allFields2.add(input);
```

---

Side note: You don't need a jQuery object around your numbers array if all you're trying to do is loop three times:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(value, index) {
    var input=$('<input/>').val(index);
    allFields2 = allFields2.add(input);
});
```

or

```
$.each([1,2,3], function(index) {
    var input=$('<input/>').val(index);
    allFields2 = allFields2.add(input);
});
```

Comment: The loop was just the first thing to come to mind to demonstrate.  Your original answer did the trick.  thank you